# Batch Script not getting executed in Mongo.exe

Tags: mongodb, batch-file

I am trying to Execute batch script to create a collection and insert data into it. It is opening Mongo.exe but it is not executing the commands.

I have tried the following ways.

```
cd  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe
mongo.exe --eval "use MyDatabase"
mongo.exe --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})"
mongo.exe --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test2' , seq : 2})"
pause
```

The above script opens Mongo.exe and does nothing other than that.
My MongoDB Shell version is 3.2.4

Comment: Try putting a `call` command before each line calling `mongo.exe`. Does it help?

Comment: I have tried putting call method but still it is doing nothing.

Comment: Strange... does is run correctly when executed directly in command line? How do you execute the batch file?
Also - you might need to put all javascript code in a single call and not break it up like this. Not sure `mongo.exe` likes it...
Look in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-eval - you might have an environment problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you commands and try:

```
cd  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe MyDatabase --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})"
mongo.exe MyDatabase --eval  "db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test2' , seq : 2})"
pause
```

or, else you can create a file (script.js) including:

```
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test1' , seq : 1})
db.TestCollection.insert({_id: 'Test2' , seq : 2})
```

and in your batch file write:

```
cd  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongo.exe MyDatabase < script.js
```

will work 100%